# How to load corectly image in thymeleaf (spring boot project)?

Tags: image, spring-boot, thymeleaf, src

I want to display the image after an error has occurred in my spring boot application. I read the documentation and tried several ways and it still doesn't work.

I read the documentation and tried several ways and it still doesn't work.
I try this:

```
<img th:src="@{/images/error_image.jpg}"/>
```

and this:

```
<img src="../static/images/error_image.jpg" th:width="1000" th:src="@{/images/error_image.jpg}"/>
```

This is my project structure:

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwibL.jpg)

Hovering over a photo with ctrl directs me to a photo, so the path is good.

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzLdS.jpg)

but all the time I see this:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xDeG.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't load image with spring boot thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083414/cant-load-image-with-spring-boot-thymeleaf)

Comment: I readed this, but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[EDIT]**

The issue is with below controller method, you should provide mapping below.

```
@GetMapping   // add mapping here
public String showSignUpForm()
{
    return "register";
}
```

Make sure static resource is not configured to different path other `static/` at your end.
If you have below configuration in application.properties, remove it.

```
spring.resources.static-locations=
```

Make sure you have below configurations in `application.properties`, spring boot's auto-configuration will set it to `resource/static/`

```
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```

It's not an issue but still, change `/images/` to `images/`

```
<img src="../static/images/error_image.jpg" th:width="1000" th:src="@{images/error_image.jpg}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried everything you talk about and it still doesn't work, but as I entered the source of the page and pressed on the image, it redirected me to my registration page. Maybe this will help in analyzing the error.
[register] (https://i.imgur.com/u8MZS0T.jpg)

Comment: @PawelPamula if it's possible, push the code to GitHub and share the link.

Comment: In index.html I want to load image
[github] (https://github.com/Volumen/training-project-pp)

Comment: @PawełPamuła I have edited the answer, the issue is with one of your request mapped method.

Comment: Thank you, now I know why this happened :)