# Using static images with spring boot and thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf and spring boot to get an email template to work. Using a spring-boot-starter-thymelelaf library. `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'`

A portion of the template (which is not working too) looks like this.

```
<p class="highlight-status" style="margin: 0; margin-bottom: 15px; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; color: #323232; font-weight: 500; font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.45; margin-right: 16px; margin-left: 4px;" th:switch="${callout}">
    <img th:case="'New'" th:src="@{img/new.jpg}" alt="New" width="104" height="22" border="0" style="display: block; margin: 0; outline: none; border: 0; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; color: #323232; font-weight: 500; font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.45;">
    ...
</p>
```

I call my template using `Context`. and the code looks like this.
`String output = templateEngine.process(Constants.TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME, new Context(Locale.getDefault(), variables));`

I can't get this image to show up on my email. I have my html file in `src/main/resources/templates` and my jpg files in `src/main/resources/static/img`

I've also tried using 
1) `th:src="@{/img/new.jpg}"` which throws an error `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Link base "/img/new.jpg" cannot be context relative (/...) unless the context used for executing the engine implements the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface (template: "email_template" - line 346, col 164)`

(I guess I can't simply use `Context-relative URLs` if I just do `new Context(...)`.)

and 2) `th:src="@{../static/img/new.jpg}"`

How do I use `WebContext` instead of `Context` or is there any other solution to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083414/cant-load-image-with-spring-boot-thymeleaf

Comment: @Rafiq I've tried this. Changed the folder name from `img` to `images` as well. It didn't work for me. Not sure what I'm doing differently.

Comment: @afzal did you get any solution?

Comment: @TheCoder I ended up uploading the images to GCP storage bucket and used `th:src="@{${gcpEndpoint} + '/new.jpg'}"`

Comment: @TheCoder I wish I had a better solution for you.

Comment: I did the same 