# Image paths are not working in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

> I am using spring configure to store and show that stored image at the
> view level. when user  search product , show the product with image
> and name but my case it only show the product name and product price
> but not showing the image of the products
> webconfig.kt

```
package com.nilmani.cmsshopingcart

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer
@Configuration
class WebConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addResourceHandlers(registry: ResourceHandlerRegistry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/media/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:/C:/Users/shyamal/Downloads/cms-shopping-cart/src/main/resources/static/media/")
    }
}
```

> product index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="/fragments/head"></head>
<body>
<nav th:replace="/fragments/nav :: nav-admin"></nav>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-2">Pages</h1>
    <a href="/admin/products/add" class="btn btn-primary mb-5">Add new</a>
    <!--suppress ThymeleafVariablesResolveInspection -->
    <div th:if="${message}" th:text="${message}" th:class="${'alert ' + alertClass}"></div>
    <div th:if="${!products.isEmpty()}">
        <table class="table sorting" id="pages">
            <tr class="home">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="product : ${products}">
                <td th:text="${product.name}"></td>
                <td>
                    <img style="width:120px;" th:src="@{'/media/' + ${product.image}}">
                </td>
                <td th:text="${cats[__${product.categoryId}__]}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.price}"></td>
                <td><a th:href="@{'/admin/products/edit/' + ${product.id}}">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a th:href="@{'/admin/pages/delete/' + ${product.id}}" class="confirmDeletion">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <nav class="mt-3" th:if="${count > perPage}">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="page-item" th:if="${page > 0}">
                <a th:href="@{${#httpServletRequest.requestURI} + '?page=__${page-1}__'}" class="page-link">Previous</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item" th:each="number :${#numbers.sequence(0,pageCount - 1)}"
                th:classappend="${page==number} ? 'active' : ''">
                <a th:href="@{${#httpServletRequest.requestURI} + '?page=_${number}'}"
                   class="page-ling" th:text="${number+1}"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item" th:if="${page < pageCount -1}">
                <a th:href="@{${#httpServletRequest.requestURI} + '?page=__${page+1}__'}" class="page-link">Next</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div th:unless="${!products.isEmpty()}">
        <h4 class="display-4">There are no pages at the moment</h4>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
<div th:replace="/fragments/footer"></div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem is with

```
.addResourceLocations("file:/C:/Users/shyamal/Downloads/cms-shopping-cart/src/main/resources/static/media/")
```

Use relative path here, or directly use,

```
<img src="../static/images/pirate.jpg" width="1000" th:src="@{images/pirate.jpg}"/>
```

It is duplicate of: [Can't load image with spring boot thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083414/cant-load-image-with-spring-boot-thymeleaf/51083565)