# How can i use css file in java/spring thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, css, spring, thymeleaf

**Hi,**
**I have an html(footer) file and a css(webflow) file. But I can't use my css file.**

This my conf class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler(
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/img/**",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations(
                        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/",
                        "classpath:/static/img/",
                        "classpath:/static/css/",
                        "classpath:/static/js/");
    }

}
```

CSS not showing/not working

[image]

**The file named webflow.css does not work on footer.html**

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{../static/css/webflow.css}" media="screen" href="../static/css/webflow.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

I use th:href label but it's not working. How can i resolve this problem?

frankly, I'm not sure if I've given the addResourceHandler the parameters correctly, but I've tried many different parameters

Comment: try this, `<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/webflow.css}" media="screen" type="text/css"/>`.  Also, in addResourceLocations, make classpath:/static the root (.addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/") )

Comment: thank you for your answer but both methods didn't work

Comment: have you implemented any security that we should know about?

Comment: could you try referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29475520/10671013) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51083565/10671013)? Although it is not for css file, it is for image in the resources folder, so I am thinking the relative path used can be extrapolated and applied in your situation.

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer. I tried both but don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `th:href="@{/css/webflow.css}"` instead of `th:href="@{../static/css/webflow.css}"`. It worked for me

Comment: it's not worked for me :(